# Ag-Grid Server Side Rendering Issue: ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I've been trying to get [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) into my react app, but I quickly hit a wall when trying to run it. To be clear, my app runs perfectly fine without the following line.

```
import {AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';
```

But when I add that line, boom. It blows up with the following error. Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks!

```
ReactScriptLoadException: Error while loading "~/build/server.bundle.js": ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined
at Script Document [3]:61033:36 -> __metadata('design:type', HTMLElement)
at Script Document [3]:61081:4
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:60680:19
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:59690:23
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:59015:23
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:55405:22
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:55307:22
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:52905:30
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:52682:27
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:52147:21
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:50357:18
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:50205:29
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:49999:15
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:49985:54
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:35328:15
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:35315:24
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:34992:21
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:125:20
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:58:88
at Script Document [3]:59:31
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:49:19
at __webpack_require__ (Script Document [3]:20:30)
at Script Document [3]:40:18
at Script Document [3]:43:10
Line: 61033
Column: 36

React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.EnsureValidState()
React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.GetEngine()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ag grid doesnt support server side rendering unfortunately